# Why does the simple code load many classes?

Tags: java, classloader

This is a very simple code:

```
package test;
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("test");
    }
}
```

I run it: java -verbose:class Test, and following is the output. Why are so many classes loaded? Isn't Java load class as needed?

```
[Opened C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_11\jre\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.lang.Object from C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_11\jre\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.io.Serializable from C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_11\jre\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.lang.Comparable from C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_11\jre\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.lang.CharSequence from C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_11\jre\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.lang.String from C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_11\jre\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.lang.reflect.GenericDeclaration from C:\Program        Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_11\jre\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.lang.reflect.Type from C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_11\jre\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.lang.reflect.AnnotatedElement from C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_11\jre\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.lang.Class from C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_11\jre\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.lang.Cloneable from C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_11\jre\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.lang.ClassLoader from C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_11\jre\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.lang.System from C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_11\jre\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.lang.Throwable from C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_11\jre\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.lang.Error from C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_11\jre\lib\rt.jar]
...
test
[Loaded java.lang.Shutdown from C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_11\jre\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.lang.Shutdown$Lock from C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_11\jre\lib\rt.jar]
```

Comment: This might help you: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-dyn0429/

Comment: Yes, this link (ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-dyn0429) has the answer to my question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Classes can themselves load classes in a transitive manner. Your program makes use of the `System` class, which may itself reference such system classes like `java.io.Serializable`.

The classes in your listing also happen to be very frequently used classes. It may simply be that the virtual machine is loading them forcibly, in order to avoid a delayed initialization. These classes are bound to be used in any non-trivial program.

Answer (score 0):

In java a class refer at least one another class (called Object). The JVM identifies these references (f.e. extends, return type, field type, implements) and load the refered classes.

In the above example:

to Java VM Loads classes when they aren't loaded

```
package test;
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("test");
  }
}
```

your class refer:
  System, Object, Class, String, some Classes from reflection package and so on.

these classes you have listed above.